# Laravel foreign key migrate

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some problems with migrations.
I already have table, that is not actually migrated with laravel, and I want to make new table with foreign key of the old one. So code looks like this:

```
Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('gameid');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('panelgameid');
            $table->string('name', 255);
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->float('minslots');
            $table->float('maxslots');
            $table->float('slotincreament');


            $table->foreign('panelgameid')->references('gameid')->on('game');
        });
```

Everything is setup correctly (I think), I'm receiving error like

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   `shark_gp`.`games` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly
>   formed") (SQL: alter table `games` add constraint
>   `games_panelgameid_foreign` foreign key (`panelgameid`) references
>   `game` (`gameid`))

What is the problem here?

Comment: if you are trying to reference to the same table, `->references('gameid')->on('game')` should be `->references('gameid')->on('games')`

Comment: It's not same table, it's from table game, games is something else

Comment: can you show us the migration of `game` table?

Comment: I don't have migration of game table, it's was added before, I'm trying to integrate with another app that is not laravel.

Comment: looks like the column `gameid` type of the `game` it's not bigInteger. You can try with `$table->unsignedInteger('panelgameid');`

Comment: Please share the definition of that `game` table

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure that the foreign key column `panelgameid` is the same type as the original key column `gameid` of the table `game`. Laravel `unsignedBigInteger` corresponds to the SQL type `UNSIGNED BIGINT`, is this the type of `gameid`?

Answer (score 0):

I think gameid in game table is just integer and not big integer, just make sure it is big integer. If its not then, you probably have to make change into your migration file for panelgameid field like

```
$table->unsignedInteger('panelgameid');
```